# cut only date and time from given input string-- Input string is Cpmplete sting such as 05-09-2018-10.13

Tags: shell, sed, command, cut

cut only date and time (i.e.**05-09-2018-10.13**) from below string

```
/pi_nfs/pixin/axpin-zhgahh/was_logs/was_admin_logs/start_WPS.log.05- 
09-2018-10.13:ADMU4000I: Server Node_axpin-zhgahh_AppClusterMember stop 
completed.
/pm_nfs/pmfin/axpin-zhgahh/was_logs/was_admin_logs/start_WPS.log.05- 
09-2018-23.00:ADMU4000I: Server Node_axpin-zhgahh_AppClusterMember stop 
completed.
```

I tried below combination but it returns me

**Command:**

```
zgrep -i "AppClusterMember stop completed" /pi_nfs/pixin/axpin 
zhgahh/was_logs/was_admin_logs/start_WPS.log.05-09-2018*|cut -d '.' -f3
```

**Output:**

```
05-09-2018-10.13:ADMU4000I: Server Node_axpin-zhgahh_AppClusterMember 
stop completed
05-09-2018-23.00:ADMU4000I: Server Node_axpin-zhgahh_AppClusterMember 
stop completed
```

**Expected Output:**

```
05-09-2018-10.13
05-09-2018-23.00
```

Comment: Is `09` part of the date in the same line or the next one?

Comment: yea its part of same line ..date 05-09-2018

Comment: Oh, ok, I posted my solution. However, you should edit the question because at the moment, it looks like there is new line after `05-` in your file sample.

Comment: Also, one more thing with zgrep I am trying to get all files which contains "stop completed" and then apply cut filter to extract date & time

Comment: I have updated my answer for that request as well. I know this is your first question here, but PLEASE NOTE that you should never change requests like this. 1) If I only had answer to your last question in my official answer, someone might down vote it because it doesn't answer your original question. 2) If you edit the question and just change requests, then answers up until now might get down voted because they don't answer your specific needs.

Comment: For the reasons stated above, please edit the question including following: 1) Change the file sample to represent the real state ( remove the spaces and new lines where they don't belong) 2) Add the additional request about the `zgrep` at the end of the qeustion under the H1 header named `EDIT`. For the future, stick to the original question or create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer

```
grep -Eo "[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}" file
```

#### Explanation

Flags:

`-E` - Use extended regex. (Allow some characters in regex to be used without escaping them.)

`-o` - Print only the matched output.

Regex:

`[0-9]` - Match a character if it is a digit from `0`-`9`.

`[0-9]{x}` - Match `x` sequential characters if they are a digit `0`-`9`.

`[0-9]{x,y}` - Match at least `x` sequential characters if they are a digit `0`-`9` but if there are more, match up to `y` of them.

`-` Has no special meaning, `grep` will try to match the exact character `-`.

`.` Means `any character` so it has to be escaped with `\` to mean exact character `.`.

## Answer for additional request in the question comments

```
zgrep -Po "[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}(?=.*stop completed\.)" file.gz
```

#### Explanation

From [zgrep manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zgrep):

> Zgrep invokes grep on compressed or gzipped files.
>   All options specified are passed directly to grep.

Therefore, I will explain only newly added flag and regex parts.

Flags:

`-P` - Use Perl regex. (Allows look-ahead)

Regex:

`(?=.*stop completed\.)` - Regex part from `(?=` to `)` is called `Positive look-ahead`.
In this case it matches the previous regex **only** if the line contains `stop completed.` afterwards.

Comment: Explanation for -1 would be great.

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but (1) Do you really believe that `05-09-7-10.13` should be matched? (2) Try to avoid presenting the same information twice.

Comment: @Scott First of all, thank you for the edit. As for questions: 1) Probably not, but I wanted to give an option. I think that I have explained decent enough so that anyone can change that and use it however they like. 2) You are right, I'll edit to remove already explained parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "/pi_nfs/pixin/axpin-zhgahh/was_logs/was_admin_logs/start_WPS.log.05-09-2018-10.13:ADMU4000I: Server Node_axpin-zhgahh_AppClusterMember stop completed." | cut -d"." -f3,4 | cut -d":" -f1
```

output is

```
05-09-2018-10.13
```

So I guess you need something like the following

```
cut -d"." -f3,4 YOUR_FILENAME | cut -d":" -f1
```

Where `YOUR_FILENAME` is the actual filename you want to use

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F: '{split($1,a,".");print a[3]"."a[4]}' input.txt

zgrep -i "AppClusterMember stop completed" /pi_nfs/pixin/axpin zhgahh/was_logs/was_admin_logs/start_WPS.log.05-09-2018* | awk -F: '{split($1,a,".");print a[3]"."a[4]}'
```

- -F: splits the records by : (colon)
- split($1,a,".") - Split the record 1 by . (dot) and keep the values in array called a
- print a[3]"."a[4] -
  print the array values.

Comment: Can you please add few words which will explain the commands?

Comment: Thanks a lot Kamaraj . Above solution works as expected and also appreciate explaining it in  detail.